# iOS Core animation and ARC

Tags: ios, animation, ios6, core-animation

I have started using CoreAnimation in my new app, i use CA to make some cool animations. But i'm new to objective C and it's difficult to me and i'm facing this big problem :

i have made a custom UIView : customView, i'm using a xib to get a user interface and set IBOutlet, custom view is a simple small view with an UIImageView inside.

In my view controller i have made a loop that insert severals customView, in this loop i set both a CAnimation for the view and for the imageView :

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i ++ )
{

    CABasicAnimation *balanceAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
  // ... set Animation here...    
    [customView.myImgView.layer addAnimation:balanceAnimation forKey:nil];

    CABasicAnimation *moveUp3Bis;
    // ... setting animation here...
    moveUp3Bis.repeatCount = 1;

    [customView.layer addAnimation:moveUp3Bis forKey:nil];

}
```

I call this loop as long as the view controller is current controller after 10 sec delay

So the views gets animate, move, and go beside the main window, but after a long time animations get slower and slower...

Of course i have understood that my loop add to the stack too many customView, the view are not released (may be because animations is still on ?)

I thought that views would be released after a while but i think the view will be moving for ever. 
May be i need to set a pointer to my view and release it after a delay ? 
I'm sure CA have planned something for case like that ?

But i do not know what can i do ?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: it's possible you are using up some other resources (like views) not animations. Are your views being removed from their parent? (`-[UIView removeFromSuperview]`)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting [`-[CABasicAnimation removedOnCompletion]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAAnimation/removedOnCompletion)?

It looks like it's default value is `YES`, so I don't think this is your problem, but it's worth looking into.

---

Have you tried using Profile to see what's slowing everything down?

Comment: yea all my animations are set to removedOnCompletion=YES

Comment: Well, i do not know what is Profile

Comment: i do not understant malloc, ... chinese to me thank you very much

Comment: Have you looked at [Measuring Core Animation Graphics Performance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MeasuringGraphicsPerformanceinYouriOSDevice/MeasuringGraphicsPerformanceinYouriOSDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH14-SW3)?

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippet that you added is hard to tell what are you doing with your views but you definitely must remove them form their parent view otherwise they won't be released.

So what I suggest is that you should try to remove the views before you start the loop and just so you have a cool animation, you should remove a view only if is not animating, for this you will have to add a key string for your animation using your current method `addAnimation:balanceAnimation forKey:nil` instead of setting it to nil and check the view's layer for `animationKeys` if the array is empty or nil then the animation is completed if not is still animating.